# Can't access endpoint which requires authentication event after authenticating

Tags: javascript, authentication, permissions, loopback

I'm trying to learn authentication using Loopback on a simple react app.
I am trying to list `Pets` which I set to only be accessible whenever the User is authenticated.

My ACLS section in the `pet.json` file currently looks like this (which was the result of following the Loopback CLI):

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
 ]
```

For logging the User in, I currently have the following code on the client side:

```
handleLogin () {
    const credentials = {
      email: 'blah@email.com',
      password: '123'
    }

    return axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/login', credentials)
      .then((result)=> {
        console.log('Login result:', result) // result object comes in just fine
        const token = result.data.id
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token)
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/Pets')
          .then( res => {
            console.log('res', res)
            this.setState({pets: res.data})
          })
      })
  }
```

Am I missing something? Does the token have to set somewhere else in the app?

Comment: for me, i'd deny everyone for everything and allow only authenticated on pet.json for certain accessType

Answer (score 1):

For authentication in Model:

```
{
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$authenticated",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
```

You also specified property:

```
{
            "accessType": "*",
            "principalType": "ROLE",
            "principalId": "$authenticated",
            "permission": "ALLOW",
            "property": ["create"]
        }
```

For **DENY**  EveryOne USE:

```
{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
```

Plz refer this link : [LoopBack authentication](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html)

You need to pass accessToken in header:

```
    ACCESS_TOKEN=6Nb2ti5QEXIoDBS5FQGWIz4poRFiBCMMYJbYXSGHWuulOuy0GTEuGx2VCEVvbpBK

# Authorization Header
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
http://localhost:3000/api/widgets

# Query Parameter
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/widgets?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still allows me access it even when I'm logged out. I will however go review the links.

Comment: I have update my answer with "DENY" EveryOne Plz check it.

{
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "DENY"
        }